# Is this the right usage of word 'sprain'?

Tags: grammaticality, descriptive-grammar

> There has come a sprain on my foot mysteriously through the night :),
>   not able to walk comfortably.

Also, is there any other general grammatical mistake in the above sentence?

Comment: It's a little weird to say "sprain on my foot" rather than "sprain in my foot".  And it would normally be "during the night" or "in the night" rather than "through the night".  The emoticon and what follows is of course informal, but OK if that's understood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it is grammatically correct to use "sprain" as a noun, which you are doing, it is much more commonly used as a verb, i.e., "I sprained my foot mysteriously in the night."

Your sentence gets the point across, but you are missing a subject for your clause after the comma - *who* is not able to walk comfortably? If I were writing this sentence, I would say:

"My foot seems to have been sprained mysteriously in the night and I can't walk comfortably"

Comment: Also, medically speaking your mysterious foot pain probably isn't an actual sprain.